# FAB Toggle hamburger to x onclick. HTML/CSS/JScript

Tags: css, animation, toggle, floating-action-button

Am having some trouble with toggling a FAB from hamburger to x.

The FAB has one primary icon, & three secondary icons. Clicking the primary icon will toggle the secondary icons vertically, & it **should** also toggle the animation from hamburger to x **at any click within the primary icon**.

Currently, my code does not toggle the animation from hamburger to x if a user were to precisely click on either of the three hamburger lines.

I do hope someone is willing to help explain where I have gone wrong, coz it just feels so close but I'm not able to figure out where my mistake is.

Tutorial Credits:

[Tran Anh Tuat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PArk1mP-9JU)

[w3newbie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMKQMrkkObc)

I am new to coding & my codes below are the combination of my efforts from studying tutorials from the above links. Will be grateful for any &  all help. Thank you in advance!

```js
let fabAnim = document.querySelector('.priFabWhite')

let fabItems = document.querySelectorAll('.secFabOrange')

showItems = () => {
    fabItems.forEach((e, index) => {
        e.style.bottom = `calc(${(index + 1.5) * 70}%)`
    })
}

hideItems = () => {
    fabItems.forEach(e => {
        e.style.bottom = `20px`
    })
}

/* Triggers click animation rotation of fabToggle button */
fabAnim.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('active')
    if (e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
        showItems()
    } else {
        hideItems()
    }
})
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 50px;
}

.wrapper > button {
    position: absolute;
    outline:transparent;
    border: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.secFabOrange{
    background-color: rgb(209, 84, 0);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: white;
}

.secFabOrange > i{
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.priFabWhite {
    background-color:white;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50px
}

.line{
    position: absolute;
    right:25%;
    height:6px;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: all cubic-bezier(0.26, 0.1, 0.27, 1.55) 0.35s;
}

.topGreen{
    top:25%;
    background: green;
}

.middleRed{
    top: 47%;
    background: red;
}

.bottomBlue{
    bottom: 25%;
    background: blue;
}

.priFabWhite.active .topGreen{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top:45%;
}

.priFabWhite.active .middleRed{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 45%;
}
.priFabWhite.active .bottomBlue{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 45%;
}


/* START popup style */
.popup {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:40%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:70%;
    height:90%;
    padding:30px 20px;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    z-index:2;
    text-align:justified;
  }
  
  .popup .title {
    margin:5px 0px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:600;
  }
  
  .popup .description{
    color:#222;
    font-size:16px;
    padding:5px;
  }
  /* END popup style */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fab Toggle Anim</title>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- START fab divs -->
    <div class="wrapper">

        <button class="secFabOrange">
            <i class='bx bx-trip'></i>
        </button>

        <button class="secFabOrange">
            <i class='bx bx-trip'></i>
        </button>

        <button class="secFabOrange">
            <i class='bx bx-exit'></i>
        </button>
      
        <button class="priFabWhite">
            <span class="line topGreen"></span>
            <span class="line middleRed"></span>
            <span class="line bottomBlue"></span>
        </button>

    </div>
    <!-- END fab divs -->

    <!-- START popup divs -->
    <div class="popup center">

        <div class="title">
          FAB Hamburger to X Animation
        </div>

        <br>

        <div class="description">
            <h3>Intention:</h3>
            
            <ol>
                <li>Anim1: Toggle <strong>secFabOrange</strong> from <strong>priFabWhite</strong> on click.</li>
                <li>Anim2: Hamburger to x.
                <li><mark>Anim3: Toggle Anim1 & Anim2 <strong>from any point within priFabWhite</strong> on click.</mark></li>
            </ol>
            
            <br>
            <h3>Problem with Current Code:</h3>
            
            <ul>
                <li>For point 3, my code toggles Anim1 & Anim2 <strong>only when white portion of priFabWhite is clicked</strong></li>
                <li>If user <strong>precisely clicks</strong> either of the three hamburger lines (green, red, blue), <strong>only Anim1 is triggered</strong>.</li>
            </ul>
            <br>
            <h3>Tutorial Credits:</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PArk1mP-9JU">Tran Anh Tuat</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMKQMrkkObc">w3newbie</a></li>
            </ul>
            
      </div>
    <!-- END popup divs -->
    
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solution for the problem. Added class avoid-clicks in html and css.

```js
let fabAnim = document.querySelector('.priFabWhite')

let fabItems = document.querySelectorAll('.secFabOrange')

showItems = () => {
    fabItems.forEach((e, index) => {
        e.style.bottom = `calc(${(index + 1.5) * 70}%)`
    })
}

hideItems = () => {
    fabItems.forEach(e => {
        e.style.bottom = `20px`
    })
}

/* Triggers click animation rotation of fabToggle button */
fabAnim.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('active')
    if (e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
        showItems()
    } else {
        hideItems()
    }
})
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 50px;
}

.wrapper > button {
    position: absolute;
    outline:transparent;
    border: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.secFabOrange{
    background-color: rgb(209, 84, 0);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: white;
}

.secFabOrange > i{
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.priFabWhite {
    background-color:white;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50px
}

.line{
    position: absolute;
    right:25%;
    height:6px;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: all cubic-bezier(0.26, 0.1, 0.27, 1.55) 0.35s;
}

.topGreen{
    top:25%;
    background: green;
}

.middleRed{
    top: 47%;
    background: red;
}

.bottomBlue{
    bottom: 25%;
    background: blue;
}

.priFabWhite.active .topGreen{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top:45%;
}

.priFabWhite.active .middleRed{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 45%;
}
.priFabWhite.active .bottomBlue{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 45%;
}


/* START popup style */
.popup {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:40%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:70%;
    height:90%;
    padding:30px 20px;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    z-index:2;
    text-align:justified;
  }
  
  .popup .title {
    margin:5px 0px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:600;
  }
  
  .popup .description{
    color:#222;
    font-size:16px;
    padding:5px;
  }
  /* END popup style */

.avoid-clicks {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fab Toggle Anim</title>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- START fab divs -->
    <div class="wrapper">

        <button class="secFabOrange">
            <i class='bx bx-trip'></i>
        </button>

        <button class="secFabOrange">
            <i class='bx bx-trip'></i>
        </button>

        <button class="secFabOrange">
            <i class='bx bx-exit'></i>
        </button>
      
        <button class="priFabWhite">
            <span class="line topGreen  avoid-clicks"></span>
            <span class="line middleRed  avoid-clicks"></span>
            <span class="line bottomBlue  avoid-clicks"></span>
        </button>

    </div>
    <!-- END fab divs -->

    <!-- START popup divs -->
    <div class="popup center">

        <div class="title">
          FAB Hamburger to X Animation
        </div>

        <br>

        <div class="description">
            <h3>Solution:</h3>
            
            <ol>
                <li>HTML: Added <strong>avoid-clicks</strong> into each span class for priFabWhite button in lines 30-32.</li>
                <li>CSS: Defined <strong>avoid-clicks</strong> in lines 123-125.
            </ol>
            
            <br>
            <br>
            <h3>Tutorial Credits:</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PArk1mP-9JU">Tran Anh Tuat</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMKQMrkkObc">w3newbie</a></li>
            </ul>
            
    </div>
    <!-- END popup divs -->
    
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```